# Enable stop token filter for standard analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch 5.1 and I want to enable the `Stop Token Filter` for the `standard` analyzer which is [disabled by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) 
The document describes how to use it in a `custom` analyzer, but I would like to know how to enable it, since it's already included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to configure the standard analyzer, see the example below how to do it with curl command([taken from docs here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/configuring-analyzers.html)):

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my_index?pretty' -d'
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "std_english": { 
          "type":      "standard",
          "stopwords": "_english_"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "my_text": {
          "type":     "text",
          "analyzer": "standard", 
          "fields": {
            "english": {
              "type":     "text",
              "analyzer": "std_english" 
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze?pretty' -d'
{
  "field": "my_text", 
  "text": "The old brown cow"
}'
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze?pretty' -d'
{
  "field": "my_text.english", 
  "text": "The old brown cow"
}'
```

Comment: Ok so basically I need to create a new analyzer.